# sql how can i use automatic timing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to MSSQL and learning more every day, I have a website that uses a field called 'LoginTime' which is an INT and whenever a user logins that field increases +1 for that particular user . What I would like to do now is to make that field automatically start back at 0 on the 1st day of each month. That way I can get averages of how many times users login within a month at the end of each month. What should i be looking into in order to allow my sql server to do this ... triggers , stored procedures etc..

Comment: Create a sproc that takes a user ID/name, and checks if the last login time was this month, if it was it increments the figure, otherwise it resets it. If you're going to audit them(which I'd recommend if you actually want to look back at the figures) then just check if a row exists for this month and that user, if it does increment it, otherwise insert it. - Personally I'd just record the log in and out times for each user as a session, and check these dates later when I want to report on it.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, I will get on that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of maintaining a counter on the table, add a new record for each successful login.  Throw a query together that aggregates login attempts by user by month-year... example as follows:

```
DECLARE @LoginTable TABLE
(
    UserName    VARCHAR(50),
    LoginTime   DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user1', '2014-01-01')
INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user1', '2014-01-02')
INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user1', '2014-01-08')
INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user1', '2014-02-01')
INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user1',' 2014-02-16')
INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user2', '2014-01-07')
INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user2', '2014-01-09')
INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user2', '2014-02-24')
INSERT INTO @LoginTable VALUES ('user2',' 2014-02-26')

SELECT UserName, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 120), 7) AS [Year-Month], COUNT(Logintime) AS Logins
FROM @LoginTable
GROUP BY UserName, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 120), 7)
```

Comment: What's with the @ character?

Comment: It's a Table variable so the example doesn't require any cleanup after you run it.  More info on table variables in SQL Server can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Drop the column from the table

Step 2 - If you don't have one already, add a table to store logins.  It's fields should be the userId and the date and time of logging in.

This way, you can see how often people logged in during any date range.